# How to make correct image to drop in respective imageview?

Tags: android, android-studio, drag-and-drop

Here i want to drag and drop correct image i.e alphabet A  from left side to its image on right side and set the score rise by 1. But after writing following code all the image get disappear when dropping outside of view. And also all the images make the score rise along with the correct one. Can anyone help me in this ??

My code for Gameactivity:

```
    img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ic_one);
    img2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ic_two);
    img3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ic_three);
    img4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ic_four);
    imgmain = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ic_main);

    img1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.a1);
img2.setImageResource(R.mipmap.a2);
img3.setImageResource(R.mipmap.a3);
img4.setImageResource(R.mipmap.a4);
imgmain.setImageResource(R.mipmap.a1);

    //setting touch listener

    img1.setOnTouchListener(listenTouch);
    img2.setOnTouchListener(listenTouch);
    img3.setOnTouchListener(listenTouch);
    img4.setOnTouchListener(listenTouch);
    imgmain.setOnDragListener(listenDrag);

    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtScore);

}

public View.OnTouchListener listenTouch = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            //setup drag
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
            v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
           v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
public View.OnDragListener listenDrag = new View.OnDragListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:


            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                //no action necessary
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                //no action necessary

                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                //handle the dragged view being dropped over a drop view
               if(v.getId() == R.id.ic_main) {
                  View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                  ViewGroup viewgroup = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                 viewgroup.removeView(view);

                  //change the text
                  score++;
                  display.setText("Your score is : "+score);


                  view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              } else {
                  View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                  view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  Context context = getApplicationContext();
                  Toast.makeText(context, "You can't drop the image here",
                          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  break;
               }
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                //no action necessary
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
};
```

}

And my layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.bhuwan.firstproject.GameActivity"
android:id="@+id/layout_game">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/ic_main"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ic_two"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="36dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/ic_one"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/ic_two"
    android:layout_marginTop="143dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/ic_three"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ic_one"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ic_one" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/ic_four"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ic_two"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ic_two"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ic_two" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/empty"
    android:id="@+id/txtScore"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="42dp" />
```

Comment: Please explian better what you have. You have five imageviews we can see. What do they contain? Pictures of letters A-E ? Now if you drag A to D then what should happen? You did not tell. Why do two imageviews contain the same picture?

Comment: I have five image view among one is main view on which images form other four image view should be dropped , on four image view i have images of letter from a - e and on main view i have one of the four images , so i need to drag and drop the correct one and for wrong ones remain as usual . @greenapps

Comment: ' all the image get disappear when dropping outside of view. '. That is because you make them invisible in onToch right away. Don't do that.

Comment: Have you seen that if(v.getId() == R.id.ic_main) is always true? So this will not help you.Instead you should compare  View view = (View) event.getLocalState(); with img1 as that is is the one with the right image. Don't remove. Just making invisible is enough.

Comment: thank you for your reply but i cant still get the exact id of view .

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand a word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic have some problems. I did some changes. Try and tell me if it better:

```
img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ic_one);
    img2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ic_two);
    img3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ic_three);
    img4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ic_four);
    imgmain = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ic_main);

    img1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.a1);
    img2.setImageResource(R.mipmap.a2);
    img3.setImageResource(R.mipmap.a3);
    img4.setImageResource(R.mipmap.a4);
    imgmain.setImageResource(R.mipmap.a1);

    //setting touch listener

    img1.setOnTouchListener(listenTouch);
    img2.setOnTouchListener(listenTouch);
    img3.setOnTouchListener(listenTouch);
    img4.setOnTouchListener(listenTouch);
    imgmain.setOnDragListener(listenDrag);

    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtScore);

}

public View.OnTouchListener listenTouch = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            //setup drag
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
            v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
            v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            img1.setOnTouchListener(null);
            img2.setOnTouchListener(null);
            img3.setOnTouchListener(null);
            img4.setOnTouchListener(null);
        }
        return false;
    }
};
public View.OnDragListener listenDrag = new View.OnDragListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                img1.setOnTouchListener(listenDrag);
                img2.setOnTouchListener(listenDrag);
                img3.setOnTouchListener(listenDrag);
                img4.setOnTouchListener(listenDrag);
                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (!getResoult()) {
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "You can't drop the image here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                //handle the dragged view being dropped over a drop view
                    View viewCorrect = (View) event.getLocalState();
                    ViewGroup viewgroup = (ViewGroup) viewCorrect.getParent();
                    viewgroup.removeView(viewCorrect);
                    //change the text
                    score++;
                    display.setText("Your score is : "+score);
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: i am sorry but i cant really figure out what  " if (!getResoult()) " really does ?  @yshahak

Comment: when view that register to DragEvent get the event DragEvent.ACTION_DROP he decide what to do and return boolean value. This will sent inside DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED to all  Views who register  to the DragEvents and they acces it via the call to getResults(). in your case whenACTION_DROP never call (the drop was outside your register view) this mean that getResults() return false

Comment: You should of course just post the code for `getResoult()` instead of talking about it. Moreover you could explain why you remove the touch listeners. Makes no sense.

Comment: "all the image get disappear when dropping outside of view" is the sense for doing that.   "just post the code for getResoult()" - be my guest